# viewstate with master and content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, viewstate

I want to disable viewstate for my entire site, but on some pages I want to enable it.

in my masterpage "main.master" I have EnableViewState="false"
in my contentpage, which has main.master as its masterpage I have EnableViewState="true"

This doesnt seem to work, the viewstate remains disabled.

So I tried some other combinations:

master: enable
content: disable
-> results in enabled viewstate

master: enable
content: disable via code-behind (Me.Master.EnableViewState = False)
-> results in enabled viewstate

It seems as if the masterpage is always overruling the contentpage, no matter what I do.

How can I disable the viewstate for the entire website, bu enable it for individual pages (I saw another issue here, but its also unsolved: http://codeasp.net/blogs/vivek_iit/microsoft.net/26/masterpage-and-viewstate-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this helpful:

> Starting a new web project, I always disable viewstate by default. If
>   I need it later, I’ll enable it on a page-by-page basis.
>
> To do this in web.config:
>
> `<pages enableViewState="false">`
>   `...`
>   `</pages>`
>
> This **IS** case-sensitive. Not sure why.

Source: [Disabling ViewState in web.config](http://thepursuitofalife.com/disabling-viewstate-in-webconfig/)

Comment: I added enableViewState="false" in web.config,but as a commenter on your link page already mentioned: it doesnt seem to work when there's a form in the masterpage. So the viewstate is now still loaded...what can I do?

Comment: Search on google, there are a number of links there, I'm just pasting one: http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Disable%20View%20State%20for%20a%20Page/Article.aspx

Comment: [Don't answer with just a link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Set `enableViewState="false"` in the `<pages>` element in Web.config instead of the master page.

Comment: On this page its discussed, but it seems its an issue with asp.net: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/10/11/masterpage-issue-with-viewstate-disabled-in-web-config.aspx
or is there a fix by now?